# AngularJS - Changing the URL used in $resource.query method

Tags: angularjs

I'm using AngularJS to integrate with a REST service which has already been built.

The REST API uses the following form for queries:

http://the.site/person/search/smith%20male (this searches for people called smith who are male)

I'm aware that this form isn't the best and will be ultimately getting the API changed to use a URL parameter.

Currently I'm just defining a resource inside my controller:

```
$scope.Summary = $resource("http://the.site/person/search");
this.Summary.query({ terms : 'smith male' });
```

but that generates URL's of the form /person/Search?terms=smith%20male

Is there a way to modify or override the URL used? I'm more familiar with Backbone where I was able to provide a url() function in my which generated the correct form of URL.

Comment: I'm not sure I would put my resource constructor function in a $scope.property like that. That's not really what that's for. A view has no reason to access a resource constructor.

Answer (score 5):

```
$scope.Summary = $resource("http://the.site/person/search/:terms");
this.Summary.query({ terms : 'smith male' });
```